# FullCalendar onClick event open Dialog in Android not working

Tags: android, jquery, dialog, calendar, fullcalendar

Here is my code for fullcalendar and i am trying to open calendar events in a dialog in Android. I tried all the ways and suggestions but failed. Can anyone suggest who has tried this in android ? Currently it is opening up in a browser in android onClick of event, i want to show in dialog. Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='../jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='../jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src="../jquery/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<link href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='../fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // US Holidays
    events: 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
            alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
            alert('View: ' + view.name);

            // change the border color just for fun
            $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

            },

        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) {
                $('#loading').show();
            }else{
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        }

    });

});

</script>
<style>

body {
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    }

#loading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    font-size: 9px;
    }

#calendar {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='loading' style='display:none'>Please Wait....Loading....</div>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Be clear with the question..where do u want to show this `html` dialog in the native android app or in the android browser?

Comment: I am showing this in webkit so jquery broswer dialog should work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and here is how to get around it.

The problem arises because in Adam Shaw's most excellent FullCalendar plugin (v1), he is attaching event handlers to the calendar events lazily, on the event container mouseover. The problem is that Android does not implement the mouseover event properly, so the click handler doesn't get initialized.

One workaround is either to change the code in his plugin around line 1707 from:
    container.unbind('mouseover').mouseover(function(ev) {

to

```
container.unbind('click').click(function(ev) {
```

However, this will require you to click on an event to initialize any other events, so if you have hover events on the calendar event (which I guess you wouldn't since you're doing mobile dev), this method won't work.

The alternative, which I do, but defeats his lazy event initialization, is to add the following to your calendar initialization options:

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(){
  // hack to trigger event binding on android chrome, which doesn't trigger mouseover events
  $('.fc-event').each(function(i, element){
    $(element).trigger('mouseover', {});
  })
}
```

What this does is immediately trigger the mouseover event on all events in the calendar, thereby triggering the attachHandler on all calendar events.